# Web Push Notification PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, web-push

I am building push notification system using PHP and javascript . 
We have PHP server which will keep on sending notification on regular interval to those client ,whose subscribed for it.
when i run the whole system in my localhost , it works fine and show me expected results,

[image]

Where as when i run it on my dev server (192.168.x.x) , it does not work and show me this error

[image]

This error is coming in both chrome and firefox.

Can anybody let me know, what wrong i am doing in my dev server ?

Comment: you will need valid ssl certificate installed on your server

Comment: In which server ? , client where i am running client code (192.168.x.x) or main notification server ,which will send notification.

Comment: on server, which publish page sending notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your website must be served over **HTTPS** (the only exception is for localhost, which can use HTTP).